# Is there a way to change the blank attribute on Django form fields to False by clicking a button?

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I am building a review form that will post to a single model in my database. This form will have multiple sections, each with its own set of questions. I want the user to be able to complete a section and hit a submit button that will save the progress and redirect them to the next section. In essence I want to create an in progress status for the review with the idea that as all sections are finished the user can hit a complete button that will run my validation on the entire form. However, I do not want to allow posting information to the database that has not been cleaned.

I've been thinking through this trying to work out what I need to do and believe the best bet would be to have a complete button on the last page that changes blank to False  for the fields of the form. I believe this would allow me to fill out each form and post it to the database as all fields would start as optional but then for that specific model instance the click of the button at the end would institute a change making all fields required, thereby running validators to ensure the form is complete. I believe this will also allow for saving progress and returning to it later if interrupted during completion of the form.

Can anyone provide any insight on if this is even possible? If so does anyone have examples that could guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the unvalidated data to the user's session. The final stage pulls all previous step data out of the session for validation. IIRC the [Django form wizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) does just this so you don't have to write it.

I might instead do this client-side, using one big (probably Crispy) form, and some client-side pseudo-submit buttons that just invoke Javascript to hide one section of the big form and reveal the next. The final one is a real submit, and redisplay of the whole thing if there are errors.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. So client-side might involve using something like React to hold state of the form as you go. I'll have to think about that. I'd ideally like to be able to have the in progress form be picked up from any computer and started again as long as the user who started was authenticated. I'll look at Crispy as an option too.

Comment: I'm not a JS programmer, so for me it would just be a little bit of JQuery to hide and show  `<div>`s with particular attributes, and `Div` objects in Crispy Form Layout objects to generate them.